# Checking Multiple Checkboxes in Android

Tags: android, checkbox

```
CheckBox checkOne = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkOne);
checkOne.setSelected(true);

CheckBox checkTwo = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkTwo);
checkTwo.setSelected(true);

CheckBox checkThree = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkThree);
checkThree.setSelected(true);
```

I am using the above code to check or uncheck multiple check boxes.

**My question is, is there any way I can get all check boxes at once? (I don't wanna use arrays)
For example, my check boxes are in a LinearLayout, so can I get all the check boxes as the child of LinearLayout?**

Comment: @SelectOr: Thank you SelectOr, thats really nice of you. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the parent LinearLayout contains **only** the checkboxes, you can do this:

```
//ll is the LinearLayout holding the children
for(int i = 0; i < ll.getChildCount(); i++) {
    ((CheckBox)ll.getChildAt(i)).setChecked(true);
}
```

if you have more views in the LinearLayout you could add a check like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ll.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View v = ll.getChildAt(i);
    if(v instanceof CheckBox) {
        ((CheckBox)v).setChecked(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: @maid450: Doesn't working. Here is the code. LinearLayout linSelect = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linSelect);
        for(int i = 0 ; i < linSelect.getChildCount() ; i++ ) {

            ((CheckBox)linSelect.getChildAt(i)).setSelected(checked);
        }

Comment: checked is the boolean variable.

Comment: does it throws an error or it just don't check/uncheck the checkboxes? I can't test it right now, but this should work... If you can add some logging or debug to see what is happening...

Comment: It doesn't check/uncheck the checkboxes.

Comment: found it, the right method is `setChecked(boolean checked)`, I update my answer