# How to check all checkboxes at some specific event in android?

Tags: android, events, list, checkbox

I am making an app which required my checkboxes to be checked at once
when i check the main checkbox.
I am using one normal checkbox widget which i am hoping will work as
my main checkbox and i am also using LIST of multiple
choice(simple_list_item_multiple_choice). Now i want to check all
these listview's checkbox when i check my main checkbox.

I am stuck at this part :( please help!!!!

Thanks,
Varundroid.

Comment: Please search SO before posting new questions. [Here is exactly what you want to accomplish](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689976/checking-multiple-checkboxes-in-android).

Comment: No Mudassir it isn't what i am exactly looking for but Aswan gave me what i was really looking for and i will keep your advise in mind while posting question next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following link is useful to you

[Correct way to check all checkboxes in ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876083/correct-way-to-check-all-checkboxes-in-listview)

Comment: Thanks Aswan it is really what i was looking for but after trying this i am getting NullPointerException. :(

Comment: Ok finally i did it. i removed that exception and now i am able to select and unselect all the checkboxes. Thanks Aswan. :-)