# Access the layout of an AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-checkbox

This is an example found at the following address: https://newbedev.com/how-to-add-a-check-box-to-an-alert-dialog. Using this code you can create an AlertDialog with checkboxs:

```
    public void dialog_box () {
      
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder (this);
        builder.setTitle ("Choose some animals");
        builder.
// add a checkbox list
        String [] animals = {"horse", "cow", "camel", "sheep", "goat"};
        boolean [] checkedItems = {true, false, false, true, false};
        builder.setMultiChoiceItems (animals, checkedItems, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
                // user checked or unchecked a box
            }
        });

// add OK and Cancel buttons
        builder.setPositiveButton ("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // user clicked OK
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton ("Cancel", null);

// create and show the alert dialog
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create ();
        dialog.show ();
    }
```

I wish I could access the layout of that dialogbox to be able to execute something similar to this ([Checking Multiple Checkboxes in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689976/checking-multiple-checkboxes-in-android)), which will allow me to access the checkboxs:

```
for (int i = 0; i <ll.getChildCount (); i ++) {
    View v = ll.getChildAt (i);
    if (v instanceof CheckBox) {
        ((CheckBox) v) .setChecked (true);
    }
}
```

ll-> the layout of the AlertDialog
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you just asking how to check all of the `Checkbox`es in the `AlertDialog`? Or do you really need access to them? 'cause the second argument in the `setMultiChoiceItems()` call determines which ones are checked when the dialog shows. You could simply pass all `true`s there.

Comment: I need to know which listboxs are marked

Comment: You can do that with the `OnMultiChoiceClickListener`, in its `onClick()` method; e.g., `checkedItems[which] = isChecked;`. In the `setPositiveButton()` `onClick()`, you can check that same array for which ones are selected.

Comment: @Mike Please sir, could you explain it better

Comment: Each time an item is checked or unchecked, the `OnMultiChoiceClickListener`'s `onClick()` method will run. The `which` parameter tells you which item in the array it is, and the `isChecked` parameter is self-explanatory. If you update the original `checkedItems` array each time – e.g., like `checkedItems[which] = isChecked;` – then you can simply loop over that array to see which items are checked: `for (int i = 0; i < checkedItems.length; i++) { if (checkedItems[i]) ... }`.

Comment: @Mike Yes, that was the solution. Thank you. If you want, provide the answer for me to accept it.

Comment: Oh, I'm good. Nothin' huge. Thank you, though. I appreciate the offer. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

- Try Something like this

> ```
> LayoutInflater layoutInflaterAndroid = LayoutInflater.from(this);
> View view = layoutInflaterAndroid.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
> builder.setView(view);
> ```

Comment: I need to know which listboxs are marked